# Convergence of Monte Carlo - Why square root n for rate?

Tags: monte-carlo, convergence, central-limit-theorem

Let $\theta_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ be the Monte Carlo estimator for $E(X)$.  Letting $\sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}(X)$, by the CLT,
$$
\sqrt{n}(\theta_n - E(X)) \xrightarrow d \mathcal{N}(0,\operatorname{Var}(X)).
$$
My question is, how does this imply the Monte Carlo estimator converges with rate $\sqrt{n}$?  As far as I know, convergence rates of $r \geq 1$ are defined for a sequence $\{x_n\}$ limiting to $L$ as
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1} - L|}{|x_n - L|^r} = c
$$
for $c > 0$.  How do we deal with $r < 1$ in this context?

Here's my attempt at understanding, not trying to force it into my preconceived notion of convergence rate.  By CLT, we can approximate probabilities involving $\theta_n$ using the CLT-implied normal distribution.  For example, a $(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval can be approximated as
$$
P\left(-z_{\alpha/2} < \frac{\theta_n - E(X)}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} < z_{\alpha/2}\right) \approx 1-\alpha,
$$
or
$$
P\left( \theta_n - z_{\alpha/2}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} < E(X) < \theta_n + z_{\alpha/2}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \right) \approx 1-\alpha
$$
where $P(Z > z_{\alpha/2}) = \alpha/2$ for $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.  So, the width of the approximate $1-\alpha$ confidence interval for $E(X)$ decreases at the rate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.  I guess this makes sense, but it's still not quite rigorous I'm afraid.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: This result _is_ the CLT, so I do not understand what you are trying to prove.

Comment: One way to think about it is what happens if we look at $n^{p} (\theta_n - \text{E}(X))$ for $p \neq 1/2$?  Because we have convergence in distribution for $p = 1/2$ the product either vanishes or blows up otherwise.